# How to put js link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have link with jQuery post action:

```
$.post('my_url', {
    'pid': pid,
    'name': $('input#nametxt').val()
}, function(data){
    $('#list').append(data);
});
```

Respose from server is for example:

```
<li>My custom name <a href="javascript:add_another('23');">Add another</a></li>
```

But this dynamically added link not working. How to do it well?

Comment: What is not working? You can't click the link or the Javascript function `add_another` is not being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it like this

Return following output from server instead of current one.

```
<li>My custom name <a href="javascript:void(0);" propId="23">Add another</a></li>
```

And do the following on your page load

```
$(function(){
  $("#list").on("click", "a", function() {
     add_another($(this).attr('propId'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make

```
$("#list").on("click", "a", function() {
   add_another($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

And responce from server:

```
<li>My custom name <a id="23">Add another</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check with your script file is on the same server(some cases where cross domain problem occurs)

Thanks,
Dhiraj

Answer (score -1):

change it to:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:add_another('23');">Add another</a></li>
```